# how to write the transition matrix of a n-circle

Tags: r, for-loop, matrix, lapply

I have wrote the code to create a blank n×n matrix, but I am not sure how to using a for loop or lapply function to fill in the matrix.

The transition probabilities of ith state in a n-circle should be a half to states i-1 and i+1, and 0 to other states.

```
C <- matrix(rep(0,n^2),ncol = n, nrow = n)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yo can create the matrix and then fill the diagonals:

```
n<-10
m<-matrix(0,n,n)
diag(m[-1,]) <-0.5 #fill the second diagonal
diag(m[,-1]) <-0.5 #fill the other second diagonal
m[1,n]<-0.5
m[n,1]<-0.5
```